# How to find data in Sequelize using data in child tables

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

So, I have this query created using Sequelize to find profiles in my database, but I want to be able to find results using the criteria that is stored in different (child) tables / models, not only on the main table.

Here it is a functional extract of my code:

**Sequelize model set-up:**

```
const Profile = sequelize.define('profiles',
    { // Database columns:
        profile_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        user_name: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
            unique: true
        }
    });

const Email = sequelize.define('profiles_emails',
    { // Database columns:
        entry_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        owner_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        email_address: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        }
    });

const Phone = sequelize.define('profiles_phones',
    { // Database columns:
        entry_id: {
            type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
            primaryKey: true,
            autoIncrement: true
        },
        owner_id: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        },
        phone_number: {
            type: Sequelize.STRING,
        }
    });
```

**Set up associations:**

```
Profile.hasMany(Email,
    { // Options:
        foreignKey: 'owner_id'
    });

Profile.hasMany(Phone,
    { // Options:
        foreignKey: 'owner_id'
    });

Profile.hasOne(Password,
    { // Options:
        foreignKey: 'owner_id'
    });
```

**Execution:**

```
// TODO: Finding by email and phone does not work because finding in other tables than the parent table is not programed.
Profile
    .findAll({
       where: {
           [Op.or]: [
               { profile_id: '665C70C2A9F9' },
               { user_name: 'user1' },
               { email_address: 'user1@mail.com' }, 
               { phone_number: '554111222' }]
        },
        include: [Phone, Email], // Tables that I want to fetch data from.
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        if (data) { console.log('Number of rows found: ' + data.length, JSON.stringify(data)) }
        else { console.log('No entries found.') }
    })
    .catch(function(data) { console.error('An error occurred while making the query:\n' + data) });
```

The "email_address" and "phone_number" columns are stored in different child tables and the Sequelize associations are already made successfully.

**Explained from a practical perspective:** I want to be able to fetch users by phone and e-mail, even though those criteria are in different, associated modules.

Any idea on how to do this? I already tried this without success: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/models-usage.html#top-level-where-with-eagerly-loaded-models

**Update according to Vivek Doshi's suggestions:**

So here is the **1st suggestion** applied:

```
Profile
    .findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { profile_id: '665C70C2A9F9' },
                { user_name: 'user1' },
                { '$profiles_emails.email_address$': 'user1@mail.com' },
                { '$profiles_phones.phone_number$': '554111222' }
            ],
        },
        include: [Phone, Email], // Tables that I want to fetch data from.
        limit: 5 // Limit of profiles to look for.
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        if (data) { console.log('Number of rows found: ' + data.length, JSON.stringify(data)) }
        else { console.log('No entries found.') }
    })
    .catch(function(data) { console.error('An error occurred while making the query:\n' + data) });
```

Which results in an error:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `profiles`.*, `profiles_phones`.`entry_id` AS `profiles_phones.entry_id`, `profiles_phones`.`owner_id` AS `profiles_phones.owner_id`, `profiles_phones`.`phone_number` AS `profiles_phones.phone_number`, `profiles_phones`.`verified` AS `profiles_phones.verified`, `profiles_phones`.`modified_time` AS `profiles_phones.modified_time`, `profiles_phones`.`modified_by` AS `profiles_phones.modified_by`, `profiles_emails`.`entry_id` AS `profiles_emails.entry_id`, `profiles_emails`.`owner_id` AS `profiles_emails.owner_id`, `profiles_emails`.`email_address` AS `profiles_emails.email_address`, `profiles_emails`.`verified` AS `profiles_emails.verified`, `profiles_emails`.`modified_time` AS `profiles_emails.modified_time`, `profiles_emails`.`modified_by` AS `profiles_emails.modified_by` FROM (SELECT `profiles`.`profile_id`, `profiles`.`user_name`, `profiles`.`modified_time`, `profiles`.`modified_by` FROM `profiles` AS `profiles` WHERE (`profiles`.`profile_id` = '665C70C2A9F9' OR `profiles`.`user_name` = 'user1' OR `profiles_emails`.`email_address` = 'user1@mail.com' OR `profiles_phones`.`phone_number` = '554111222') LIMIT 5) AS `profiles` LEFT OUTER JOIN `profiles_phones` AS `profiles_phones` ON `profiles`.`profile_id` = `profiles_phones`.`owner_id` LEFT OUTER JOIN `profiles_emails` AS `profiles_emails` ON `profiles`.`profile_id` = `profiles_emails`.`owner_id`;

An error occurred while making the query:
SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'profiles_emails.email_address' in 'where clause'
```

And here is the **2nd suggestion** applied:

```
Profile
    .findAll({
        where: {
            [Op.or]: [
                { profile_id: '665C70C2A9F9' },
                { user_name: 'user1' },
            ],
        },
        include: [{
            model : Phone,
            where : { phone_number: '554111222' } ,
            required : false
        }, {
            model : Email,
            where : { email_address: 'user1@mail.com' } ,
            required : false
        }],
        limit: 5 // Limit of profiles to look for.
    })
    .then(function(data) {
        if (data) { console.log('Number of rows found: ' + data.length, JSON.stringify(data)) }
        else { console.log('No entries found.') }
    })
    .catch(function(data) { console.error('An error occurred while making the query:\n' + data) });
```

Which results in:

```
Executing (default): SELECT `profiles`.*, `profiles_phones`.`entry_id` AS `profiles_phones.entry_id`, `profiles_phones`.`owner_id` AS `profiles_phones.owner_id`, `profiles_phones`.`phone_number` AS `profiles_phones.phone_number`, `profiles_phones`.`verified` AS `profiles_phones.verified`, `profiles_phones`.`modified_time` AS `profiles_phones.modified_time`, `profiles_phones`.`modified_by` AS `profiles_phones.modified_by`, `profiles_emails`.`entry_id` AS `profiles_emails.entry_id`, `profiles_emails`.`owner_id` AS `profiles_emails.owner_id`, `profiles_emails`.`email_address` AS `profiles_emails.email_address`, `profiles_emails`.`verified` AS `profiles_emails.verified`, `profiles_emails`.`modified_time` AS `profiles_emails.modified_time`, `profiles_emails`.`modified_by` AS `profiles_emails.modified_by` FROM (SELECT `profiles`.`profile_id`, `profiles`.`user_name`, `profiles`.`modified_time`, `profiles`.`modified_by` FROM `profiles` AS `profiles` WHERE (`profiles`.`profile_id` = 'user1' OR `profiles`.`user_name` = 'jorge') AND ( SELECT `owner_id` FROM `profiles_phones` AS `profiles_phones` WHERE (`profiles_phones`.`phone_number` = '9' AND `profiles_phones`.`owner_id` = `profiles`.`profile_id`) LIMIT 1 ) IS NOT NULL LIMIT 5) AS `profiles` INNER JOIN `profiles_phones` AS `profiles_phones` ON `profiles`.`profile_id` = `profiles_phones`.`owner_id` AND `profiles_phones`.`phone_number` = '9' LEFT OUTER JOIN `profiles_emails` AS `profiles_emails` ON `profiles`.`profile_id` = `profiles_emails`.`owner_id` AND `profiles_emails`.`email_address` = 'user1@mail.com';
```

This one works and finds rows. But it fetches results associated to the results of the "main" model (this is, the data is found by userid / user_name and then, those results will be accompanied or not depending on wether the other data (email and phone) matched). This is not what I want now, **I want to be able to find a full profile with all its data and with the same structure using the criteria / columns in other tables.**

Answer (score 2):

Here you go , this is how you can get the expected result with Sequelize

```
Profile
    .findAll({
       where: {
           [Op.or]: [
               { profile_id: '665C70C2A9F9' },
               { user_name: 'user1' }
           ]
        },
        include: [ { 
                model : Phone ,
                where : { phone_number: '554111222' } ,
                required : false // as you want it in OR relation relation
            }, { 
                model : Email
                where : { email_address: 'user1@mail.com' } ,
                required : false // as you want it in OR relation relation
            }]
    })
```

**OR**

```
Profile
    .findAll({
       where: {
           [Op.or]: [
               { profile_id: '665C70C2A9F9' },
               { user_name: 'user1' },
               { '$profiles_emails.email_address$': 'user1@mail.com' }, 
               { '$profiles_phones.phone_number$': '554111222' }]
        },
        include: [Phone, Email], // Tables that I want to fetch data from.
    })
```

Comment: Thank you! But unfortunately it doesn't seem to work either.

The first example does not cause error, but still does not find results from the columns email_address and phone_number.

In the last example, I get "SequelizeDatabaseError: Unknown column 'profiles_emails.email_address' in 'where clause'".

Comment: Please post your errors and raw query generated by sequlize

Comment: I updated my question with the result of your examples, please let me know if something is not clear enough :)

Comment: The problem with the provided second solution was if you add offset and limit the columns of the child table used in the where object will be an unknown column.